# Android how to apply flip rotation animation on each element of grid view?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation, android-imageview

i have a grid view and i want to apply flip rotation animation on every child of grid view.
when user touch on a grid view element it perform flip rotation animation and change image.
and **i use table layout to create grid of images**.

i want to perform like this[Plz check once](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html)

this performs on one(layout).
but i want to perform on a 48 elements.
any help from someone....
plz give suggestion soon..
thanks in advance....

Answer (score 4):

One of the most convincing 3D flip animation I've seen is done here https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition.

A lot of the other tutorials and sample codes don't produce believable 3D flips. A simple rotation on the y-axis isn't what's done in iOS.

There is also a video here: http://youtu.be/52mXHqX9f3Y

So, to flip each grid element, simple call:

```java
ViewFlipper viewFlipper = getViewFlipperForItem(i);
AnimationFactory.flipTransition(viewFlipper, FlipDirection.LEFT_RIGHT);
```

Where `getViewFlipperForItem` is a method you implement to get the `ViewFlipper` on that cell. I suggest you add each cell as a `ViewFlipper` (or `ViewAnimator`) and add the images you intend to flip within the `ViewFlipper` (or `ViewAnimator`). If this isn't clear to you, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code for adding flip animation to a view in android.

```
    final ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotationY", 0.0f, 360f);
            animation.setDuration(3000);
            animation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
            animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            animation.start();
            view.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ephraim, 
         I used view flipper in my project and used that library that you have mentioned. It looks great and it help me out. Please any one who want to animate his view like rotate should use this library.

https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition.